# Symmetric Matrix over a finite field of Characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be a $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrix over a finite field of Characteristic 2. Suppose that the entries in the diagonal of $M$ are all zero, and $n$ is an odd number. I found that the rank of $M$ is at most $n-1$. Is my observation true? How do we prove it? Thanks

Comment: I believe this has something to do with symplectic bilinear forms in characteristic two having an even rank. See for example [Keith Conrad's notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. In general, over any field, if $M$ is a skew-symmetric matrix with a zero diagonal (i.e. if it represents an alternating bilinear form), the rank of $M$ must be even.

Suppose $M\ne0$. By a simultaneous permutation of the rows and columns of $M$, we may assume that $c_1:=m_{21}=m_{12}\ne0$. So, we may write
$$
M=\pmatrix{R&-Y^T\\ Y&Z},\ \text{ where }\ R=c_1\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}
$$
and $Z$ is a symmetric matrix with a zero diagonal. Thus $M$ is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to $R\oplus S$, where $S=Z+YR^{-1}Y^T$ is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $R$ in $M$. Since $Z$ and $R^{-1}$ represent alternating bilinear forms, so must $S$. Therefore, we may proceed recursively and $M$ will eventually be congruent to a matrix of the form $c_1R\oplus c_2R\oplus\cdots\oplus c_kR\oplus0$. Hence its rank is even.